# How is the standard error of a survival function estimate computed?

Tags: estimation, survival

Say I have a lifetime variable with survival probability $S(t|\theta)$, and I estimate this probability by 
$$\hat{S}(t|\theta)=S(t|\hat{\theta})$$
How would we go about deriving the standard error of this estimate?
Is there a general procedure to follow, or does it depend on the form of the hazard function of $T$?

Comment: It may help to clarify how you would like to estimate $S$: is this the Kaplan Meier estimator you are interested in? Cox-PH model with Kaplan Meier base distribution? Or a fully parametric model?

Comment: I am working with a semiparametric additive model, specifically with hazard
$\lambda(t|\alpha,\beta(t))=X^T\beta(t)+g(Y^T\alpha)$